# Is there a python package that can geoparse using fuzzy matching?

Tags: python

I have a string with a misspelled country that looks like this:

```
"My friend is from ejypt"
```

Is there a package that i could use to discern if a country is mentioned in the string?

Example of code and output:

```
packageFunction("My friend is from ejypt")

>>'Egypt'
```

***Anything that is similar would suffice.***

***Things I have tried:***
I have tried using geotext for this task. As far as I know, geotext is case-sensitive and doesn't use fuzzy matching, so it cannot be used on misspelled words or case-sensitive words.